# How to click on an input element using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, selenium4

I'm trying to click on the tab with text as *`Python`* within the [Selenium documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/) website.

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="tabsetcode2" id="tab1code2" aria-controls="pythoncode2">
```

But I'm facing `TimeoutException`:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Code trials:

```
driver.get('https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/')
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[aria-controls='pythoncode2']"))).click()
```

Can anyone help me out to click on the *`Python`* tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can click on the label instead and it works.

```
driver.get('https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/')
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@for='tab1code2']"))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try waiting by xpath

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '*//div[@class="tabset"]/label[2]'))).click()
```

If still doesn't work, try waiting till visible

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '*//div[@class="tabset"]/label[2]'))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is a preference to use Id > Css selector > XPaths. So the example code could have been `(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#pythoncode2")` or better `(By.ID, "pythoncode2")`.

However, that is not a clickable the element anyway, so despite waiting 20 seconds, it would always reach timeout waiting for it to become 'clickable'. (the circle of the radio button has the styling of `left -1704px` which is off the screen if you go into "developer mode" on the browser via F12 and select that tab. The driver consider anything outside its viewport as unclickable)

The clickable element is the target label; there is no Id, but you can find it by CSS: `(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "label[for=tab1code2]")`

Here's my working code to prove it working:

```
from selenium import webdriver

if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver")
    driver.get('https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/')
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("label[for=tab1code2]").click()
```

Comment: _...clickable element is the target label..._ shouldn't `<input>` be the clickable element?

Comment: It would be relating to the clickable 'radio button circle' being off the screen. Go into "developer mode" on the browser via F12 and select that element, the styling is computed to be `left -1704px`. The selenium driver can only click on an element within the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

The  element is indeed clickable. But it is bounded with a label tag.

For more information, about binding label and info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)

Using `EC.element_to_be_clickable` also ensure that the element is visible which is not the case.

```
class element_to_be_clickable(object):
    """ An Expectation for checking an element is visible and enabled such that
    you can click it."""
```

You can confirm that it is clickable by calling `is_enabled`. This method only validate that the attribute `disabled` is not false.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[aria-controls='pythoncode2']").is_enabled()
```

Or

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[aria-controls='pythoncode2']").get_attribute('disabled') != "true"
```

Result:

```
True
```

But the `EC.element_to_be_clickable` also calls to `is_displayed` to determine if the element is visible as well

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[aria-controls='pythoncode2']").is_displayed()
```

Result:

```
False
```

This is why, no matter how long you wait, it will never become true.

To click on the input element, you might target the label element instead. They are bound together with the attribute `for=id`

In your case

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[for="tab1code2"]')
```

Also:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[for="tab1code2"]').is_enabled()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[for="tab1code2"]').is_displayed()
```

Both returns: `True`

Answer (score 0):

If you try to click the element with the css selector you've chosen, the following exception is thrown:

```
ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable"
```

The reason why, is the fact the `type="radio"` attribute.

Instead of that, you should try to click the label element underneath with the following css selector:

```
("label[for=tab1code2]")
```

So, your code should look like:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "label[for=tab1code2]"))).click()
```